# umask not work on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, 19.10, umask

everybody,

i have found some postings about this problem but none of the solutions work for me. I want to set the UMASK system-wide on 007. I am using Ubuntu 19.10 with the default desktop. I have edited the following files:

[/etc/login.defs]

```
UMASK           007
USERGROUPS_ENAB no
```

[/etc/profile]

```
# added at the end
umask 007
```

[/etc/pam.d/common-session]

```
session optional                        pam_umask.so umask=0007
```

Then restart the computer and log on. If I check the UMASK in the terminal now, it is still 0022

```
s.gehr@pc001:~$ umask
0022
```

What am I doing wrong?

with best
sven

Answer (score 0):

With credits to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220531/how-to-set-system-wide-umask, edit the file `/etc/login.defs` and set your desired umask value. By default, the line reads

```
UMASK       022
```

This is because Ubuntu uses PAM ((Pluggable Authentication Modules for Linux) to set the umask. PAM is a system that provides support for dynamic authentication.

Nothing else at the system level can override the settings applied through PAM. However, users always can set their own `umask` value if they wish.

Comment: I use the default gnome terminal

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: @AndrewKoster Things indeed may have changed since Ubuntu 19.10. Of course, I assume you have restarted the system to have the change take effect.

Comment: @vanadium It's hard to say. This UMASK system is one of several things that affect the outcome. In the end, the only thing that ever makes files accessible to multiple users 100% of the time is making sure that the code which creates a file always sets its permissions to 666 (or 777 for directories and executable files) right after creating it, because only the owner is guaranteed to be able to make this change.

Comment: @AndrewKoster The umask value is what controls how permissions will be of files saved by any application. Root can set the default system value, the user can optionally override it.

Comment: @vanadium That's one of the many things that controls the default permissions. It also depends on what language or program is being used to create the file, how it's implemented, and what options exist and are being used when creating the file.