# How to set umask to u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx for all ways of logging in without root privileges on 20.04.2?

Tags: gnome, permissions, ssh, login, nautilus

I am working on an Ubuntu 20.04.2 box that I do not have root privileges on.  I would like to set my umask to `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx` (aka 022) no matter how I log in.  I want to set it for GNOME sessions launched by GDM (for Nautilus in particular), for ssh logins, for console terminal logins, everything.  I want it to be the case that however I log in, and however I create a new file, the umask in effect is `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`.

I've tried adding the line

```
umask u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
```

to my .profile, and my .bash_profile looks like:

```
source $HOME/.profile
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

This works for ssh logins and console terminal logins, but not for GNOME sessions (not for files/folders created with Nautilus in the GNOME session, in particular).

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411060/137608):

```
$ systemctl --user edit dbus
```

In the file that gets opened, just write:

```
[Service]
UMask=022
```

The file gets saved in `.config/systemd/user/dbus.service.d/override.conf`.

I am not sure if Nautilus is launched by `systemd`.

**Related**:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/6s2w0l/anybody_found_a_workaround_for_gnome_318_bug_that/
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254378/how-to-set-umask-for-the-entire-gnome-session/411060#411060
3. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4722581
4. [umask not work on ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200107/umask-not-work-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: This seems to work for nautilus and gedit, but not for LibreOffice...

Comment: Awarded the bounty to this answer, because it makes the most 'headway' against the problem.  But it's so frustrating to me that this question doesn't have a simple, straightforward answer.  And doubly so b/c setting umask in .profile worked in previous versions of Ubuntu!

Comment: @AdamL.Taylor - As stated in the links provided, this won't work for all applications. That is apparently the state of matters.
It's not what you would like to hear, but that doesn't mean there **is** an alternative.

Comment: My question was "How do I do X in Ubuntu 20.04.2?".  The answer, seemingly, is "There's no simple way to do X in Ubuntu 20.04.2."  I think it's OK to acknowledge that this situation is suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `~/.bash_profile` is executed — I don't even have such a file.

However, you want to add your `umask` command to `~/.bashrc`, not to `~/.profile`. Add this line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
umask u=rwx,go=rx
```

`~/.profile` by default contains the following command to include `~/.bashrc`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Thus, adding `umask` to `~/.bashrc` covers both of them, which is important.

I set my `umask` like this some time ago, and it has worked very well in Ubuntu 20.04.

Be aware that if your Home folder doesn't allow access, other people can't access its contents anyway. So, you want to also set your Home folder permissions accordingly:

```
chmod u=rwx,go=rx /home/${USER}
```

---

**A note about security**

I hope that you realise what a serious security issue this could be. You should use this specific user *only* for public-safe data. So, no passwords apart from your login password. Don't sign into anything at all (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Thunderbird, etc.); don't even sign into a website (e.g. your bank) on a browser. Otherwise, anyone can access your passwords.

If you are the *only* person who can access this computer, you're probably fine, although the `o=rx` is a bit concerning.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to answer, but setting the umask in .bashrc does not solve the problem I described in the question.  It solves it for programs launched from a bash shell, but not for programs launched directly from the GNOME shell.

Comment: Also, the default Ubuntu umask is u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx, so if anything what I propose is more secure than the default.  Also, .bash_profile is sourced for login bash shells when it exists.  .profile is only sourced by bash login shells if .bash_profile is missing.  So the effect of my .bash_profile is similar to your code snippet to source .bashrc from .profile, but it seems simpler to me, since I don't have to explicitly test for a bash shell.  Generally, I try to follow the practices described in https://superuser.com/a/789465/310157 when it comes to .profile, .bash_profile, and .bashrc.

Comment: That's strange, @AdamL.Taylor , because my experience is different. I wonder why? I read that future versions of Ubuntu will change their default to `ug=rwx,o=`, which makes better sense. If you set your home folder to this, it will prevent others from accessing your folder anyway: `chmod --recursive o= ${USER}`.

Comment: I just tried it again on a Vanilla Ubuntu 20.04.2 VM.  I added `umask u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx` to .bashrc, as you suggest.  Then I logged out, logged in again (graphical login, i.e. via GDM), launched Nautilus by double-clicking on the icon, then created a new folder in Nautilus.  Permissions for the new folder were `drwxrwxr-x`, i.e. still what you'd expect with the default umask.

Comment: @AdamL.Taylor — And, now it's happening to me as well. I don't know if Nautilus ignores the setting? Sorry, it seems that my solution isn't suitable. I would still run the `chmod` to set your home folder, because that prevents others from accessing anything within your folder even when its permissions are set to global (you can test it yourself — it takes precedence in preventing access).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 1 :)

For gnome3 sessions add a umask to

```
$HOME/.gnomerc
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 20.04.2...